# issues with RabbitListenerTestHarness, it is not working

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, junit5, spring-amqp

I am trying to mock @RabbitListener. For this i am using RabbitListenerTestHarness but this doesn't seems to work.
Below is my project structure

**Main class**

```
@Component
public class ABC {

@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

@RabbitListener(id="id", queues="${queue}")
 public void receiveMessage(String message) {
publishMsg(message);      
}

public void publishMsg(String msg){
    amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "",msg); 
}

}
```

**test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ABCTest {

@Autowired
private RabbitListenerTestHarness harness; 

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
@Test
public void testSendtoQueue() throws Exception {
    ABC listener = this.harness.getSpy("id");
    assertNotNull(listener);

    LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer answer = this.harness.getLatchAnswerFor("id", 1); 
    doAnswer(answer).when(listener).receiveMessage(any(String.class)); 

    String data = getMockString("src/test/resources/rabbitMQ-data.json");
    
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("Queue-name", data);

    //assertTrue(answer.await(10));
   verify(listener,times(1)).receiveMessage("data");
}
```

}

and on running above it gives me error as below

```
Wanted but not invoked:
customPublisherSubscriber.receiveMessageFromResponseQ(
"data"
);
-> at aero.sita.sp.spm.service.ABC.testSendtoQueue(CustomPublisherSubscriberTest.java:67)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at aero.sita.sp.spm.service.ABC.testSendtoQueue(CustomPublisherSubscriberTest.java:67)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

i was referring to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc.

I am struggling to understand as i am trying to verify spy object for message received or not, but it is reporting issues related to mock object. Could you please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `@RabbitListenerTest`, which is needed to enable the harness.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#test-harness

Also,

```
Wanted but not invoked:
customPublisherSubscriber.receiveMessageFromResponseQ(
"data"
);
```

I see no reference to that method anywhere in your test or code.